# How to restrict/prevent turing completeness in a generics system

Tags: haskell, generics, programming-languages

I want to write a generics system for a simple programming language. I do not want to deal with complex generics that can compute things. For example the C++ templating language is accidentally turing complete, and haskell with fundeps can do type level arithmetic. What restrictions on the generics system would I need to place to make it non turing complete?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is on topic on SO. [CS.SE] or [programmers.SE] might be better places, but I'm not sure on that either.

Comment: The haskell type system can only do things like arithmetic if you enable an extension to allow it. Generally this will be Undecidable Instances or the like. Otherwise the compiler will reject anything that could be non-terminating, which is any type family application withing a type family definition, or an instance constraint which is no smaller than the instance head. These are two very specific metrics for the Haskell (GHC) type system in particular - I'm not sure to which degree they will generalize.

Comment: Ensuring termination will surely make it non Turing complete. However, this does not imply that the system is "simple" or efficiently implementable -- e.g. Agda's type system is not Turing complete, yet in practice you can write almost everything in that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about theoretical computer science, in particular type system design, which is a topic suited for either [cs.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) or [cstheory.SE](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The answer is ... anything that would prevent it from simulating an arbitrary Turing machine. It's not quite clear where you want to go with this question, so I'm voting to close it as "too broad". Although you may want to look at existing non-Turing complete systems, like Coq, Agda, and BlooP (the latter likely being the easiest to comprehend), and what restrictions they enforce.

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_computation. You want something weaker than a Turing machine.

Comment: The simplest ways are explicitly limiting time or space to some arbitrary number of steps or bytes. These restrictions will lead to ill-behaved systems, but they are useful in practice nonetheless.

Comment: After researching BlooP, I found another language with a simple implementation: PL-{GOTO}. It is also a primitive recursive function language. However, it looks like such a function can indeed have a lot of non-simple behavior.